# Como ler dados de um arquivo em c e tratar como string?

Tags: c

como ler os dados de um arquivo em c e atribuir a uma string?

arquivo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define CONFIG "config.ini"

void main()
{
    char *data, *data1, *stream;
    FILE* arquivo;
    arquivo = fopen(CONFIG, "r");

    /*

    // data = fgets(stream, sizeof(arquivo), arquivo);
    // data1 = fscanf(arquivo, "%s", stream);

    */

    // printf("%s\t%s\n", data, data1);
    fclose(arquivo);
    // fopen(CONFIG, "w");
    return;
}
```

config.ini

```
Lorem ipsum auctor curabitur at justo maecenas hendrerit feugiat, adipiscing augue
accumsan ornareeu nunc iaculis cubilia, sodales quisque bibendum dapibus ullamcorper
ornare diam. consectetur pretium eros velit ante pellentesque taciti ullamcorper interdum
gravida himenaeos viverra mauris luctus hendrerit habitasse arcu fringilla, praesent
habitant mi facilisis curae fames quam sapien.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para conseguir ler tudo precisa de saber primeiro quantos bytes o arquivo tem.

O que precisa de fazer é:

- Posicionar-se no fim com [`fseek`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/) e flag `SEEK_END`
- Descobrir qual o byte em que está com [`ftell`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ftell/)
- Ler essa quantidade com de bytes com [`fread`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/) a partir do inicio

Exemplo:

```
void main()
{
    char *data, *data1, *stream;
    FILE* arquivo;
    arquivo = fopen(CONFIG, "r");

    fseek (arquivo, 0, SEEK_END); //posicionar-se no fim
    long dimensao = ftell (arquivo); //descobrir a dimensão
    fseek (arquivo, 0, SEEK_SET); //voltar ao inicio
    data = (char*) malloc ((dimensao+1) * sizeof(char) ); //alocar espaço para ler tudo

    if(data){ //se conseguiu alocar
        fread (data, 1, dimensao, arquivo); //ler tudo
        data[dimensao] = '\0'; //colocar o terminador
    }

    fclose(arquivo);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado novamente Isac

Comment: A string contida no ponteiro `data` não está bem formada pois não possui o terminador `\0` e `malloc()` não aloca um byte a mais para a inclusão desse terminador.

Comment: @Lacobus Bem visto, foi algo que me escapou. Obrigado por me avisar

Comment: Não conhecia esse `ftell`. Sempre aprendo coisas novas lendo suas respostas

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Que é bem util por sinal, para casos com este.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar as funções `fread()` e `realloc()` dentro de um loop.

A cada iteração do loop, `fread()` fica responsável por ler um pequeno bloco do arquivo de entrada, enquanto `realloc()` fica responsavel por gerenciar a memória necessária para acomodar cada bloco lido.

Segue um exemplo (testado) ilustrando a ideia:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF_MAX_TAM (128)

int carregar_arquivo( const char * arq, char ** str )
{
    unsigned char buf[ BUF_MAX_TAM ] = {0};
    int total = 0;
    int n = 0;
    char * p = NULL;
    FILE * pf = NULL;

    pf = fopen( arq, "r" );

    if(!pf)
        return -1;

    p = malloc( 1 );

    while( (n = fread( buf, 1, sizeof(buf), pf )) != 0 )
    {
         p = realloc( p, total + n + 1 );
         memcpy( p + total, buf, n );
         total += n;
    };

    p[ total ] = '\0';
    *str = p;

    fclose(pf);

    return total;
}


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    int tam = 0;
    char * p = NULL;

    tam = carregar_arquivo( argv[1], &p );

    printf("%s\n\n", p );

    printf("Bytes lidos: %d\n", tam );

    free(p);

    return 0;
}
```

Testando:

```
./teste config.ini
Lorem ipsum auctor curabitur at justo maecenas hendrerit feugiat, adipiscing augue
accumsan ornareeu nunc iaculis cubilia, sodales quisque bibendum dapibus ullamcorper
ornare diam. consectetur pretium eros velit ante pellentesque taciti ullamcorper interdum
gravida himenaeos viverra mauris luctus hendrerit habitasse arcu fringilla, praesent
habitant mi facilisis curae fames quam sapien.

Bytes lidos: 389
```