# Dúvida com arquivos excel

Tags: c, microsoft-excel, arquivo

Tenho uma lista de datas em um arquivo BTH.cvs excel. Quero copiar todo o arquivo para outro novo.cvs, porém o a.exe para de funcionar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv){
    FILE *in = fopen("BTH.csv", "r");
    FILE *out = fopen("novo.csv", "w");



        while(!feof(in)){
            int num;
            fscanf(in, "%d", &num);

            fprintf(out, "%d", num);

        }




    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que o arquivo csv tem mais coisas para alem de números que não irá conseguir ler com `%d`. Apesar de poder tentar alterar o seu algoritmo para esse caso, por exemplo com [`sscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/) acho que é mais facil seguir por outro caminho.

Utilizando a mesma ideia de esta [minha outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/241222/como-ler-dados-de-um-arquivo-em-c-e-tratar-como-string/241239#241239) pode fazer assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *in = fopen("BTH.csv", "r");
    fseek (in, 0, SEEK_END); //posicionar-se no fim
    long dimensao = ftell (in); //descobrir a dimensão
    fseek (in, 0, SEEK_SET); //voltar ao inicio

    //alocar espaço para ler tudo
    char *dados = (char*) malloc(dimensao * sizeof(char)); 

    if(dados){ //se conseguiu alocar
        fread (dados, 1, dimensao, in); //ler tudo
        FILE *out = fopen("novo.csv", "w"); //abrir o destino para escrita
        fwrite(dados, dimensao, 1 , out); //escrever todo o conteudo
        fclose(out);
    }

    fclose(in);
    return 0;
}
```

Tem várias outras alternativas também como por exemplo, executar uma copia de arquivo pelo sistema operativo com o comando apropriado.

Seria também relevante escrever as respetivas mensagens de erro quer para quando não conseguiu alocar o espaço necessário de leitura, quer para quando a abertura de qualquer um dos `FILE*` não teve sucesso.